# What microdata type to choose on mixed category?

Tags: microdata, rich-snippets

I have a mixed category of articles which can range from review, blogpost, product or software something like this [blog post on You!Joomla](http://www.youjoomla.com/youjoomla-blog.html). Does anyone know what type of microdata to choose from schema.org?

If I choose

```
itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Blog"
```

and I have a Product in a mix, I get the next error on the [Structured Data Testing Tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets)

`Error: Page contains property "product" which is not part of the schema.`

**UPDATE:**

does anyone see an issue with this mix?

Category that holds all of them to be

`http://schema.org/Blog`

articles in that category list

`http://schema.org/CreativeWork`

and once you go in article it will have own type like Product , book etc.

Comment: Which markup generated the quoted error? It sounds like you used a `product` property (e.g. `itemprop="product"`), which doesn’t exist in Schema.org.

Comment: It would be useful to see some minimal (!) examples of your structure and pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what all you need so it will be hard to speak to your particular needs. But this is what I think is going on and the solution is really really simple.

Each entity/data pair belongs to a type within the schema. You cannot mix them. But you can use any or all of them any time any way you want. Here is what I mean. For Articles, they live within the CreativeWork type. So does Blog. But Product does not. You can use any and each of these, but what you have to remember is to nest what should be nested- that is- Blog within CreativeWork, and close each type before referencing another type- such as CreativeWork/Blog before referencing Product. It will take some work to organize your content in such a way that this works, but it should be easy enough. It just takes a bit of planning. Otherwise you are confusing entities within types and that just does not work.